# Python: How to move files in a structured folder based on year/month/date format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, pyspark

Currently I have a spark job that reads the file, creates a dataframe, does some transformations and then move those records in "year/month/date" format.
I am achieving this by:

```
df.write.option("delimiter", "\t").option("header", False).mode(
            "append"
        ).partitionBy("year", "month", "day").option("compression", "gzip").csv(
            config["destination"]
        )
```

I want to achieve the same by pythonic way. So, in the end it should look like:

```
data/2022/04/14
data/2022/04/15
```

Comment: Use `datetime` library.

Comment: In your case currently the folder structure - `YYYY/MM/DD` will start after your `config['destination']` since you are using `partitionBy`

AWS s3 takes care of creating the necessary write path if it does not exists , the key here would be to create the intended path pattern within `config['destination']`. 

Suggest you to modify your destination variable

Comment: @Vaebhav Since this is a cron job. Files gets stored in an intial bucket every hour and from there, daily subfolders have to be created. How do I create path pattern for the same?

Comment: @DKNY can you help me with the script of the same? I tried already something with the datetime library but didn't worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question , instead of using `partitionBy` you can also modify your `config['destination']` , as s3 will take care of the necessary folder creations underneath the s3 path

```
s3_dump_path = config["destination"] ### 's3:/test-path/'
>>> curr_date = datetime.now().date()
>>> year,month,day = curr_date.strftime('%Y'),curr_date.strftime('%m'),curr_date.strftime('%d')
>>> s3_new_path = '/'.join([s3_dump_path,year,month,day])
>>> s3_new_path
's3:/test-path//2022/04/14'
>>> config["destination"] = s3_new_path

df.write.option("delimiter", "\t").option("header", False).mode(
            "append"
        ).option("compression", "gzip").csv(
            config["destination"]
        )
```